# Opera 12 crashes on clicking outgoing links on Facebook

Tags: windows-7, opera, facebook

My problem is as follows:

Since my Update to Opera 12 (from Opera 11.6x) the browser crashes every time I click a link on Facebook that leads to another website.

As I have about 80k mails in Opera mail that I don't want to lose, a simple: delete everything, start from scratch is not good. Which files could cause the problem and how do I keep my mails save from uninstalling/reinstalling Opera?

Edit: Operating System: Windows 7 64bit version.

Comment: Do you use any extensions, UserJS or urlfilter.ini?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Operating System added, further information: does not happen with certain links (pictures, I assume, but i was unable to verify this). normal URLs always crash the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though it might be some JavaScript that gets executed when you click on links. To confirm, just turn JavaScript off, load a page, and click on a link that was crashing before. I'm assuming you've sent Opera a crash report or submitted a bug report so they can fix it - even bad JavaScript shouldn't crash a browser. To exclude the possibility of any extensions or customisations being responsible for your issues, simply do a vanilla install of the same version to a different location on your hard drive and test in that.

As to saving your mail, simply right-click on your mailbox and choose "Export" to save it somewhere in the standard `.mbs` mailbox format. You can later import that file into a new installation or a different email client.